# Breakdown of fixture setup time in py.test

Tags: pytest

I have some py.test tests that have multiple dependent and parameterized fixtures and I want to measure the time taken by each fixture. However, in the logs with `--durations` it only shows time for `setup` for actual tests, but doesn't give me a breakdown of how long each individual fixture took.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything builtin for that, but you can easily implement yourself by using the new [pytest_fixture_setup hook](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_fixture_setup) in a `conftest.py` file.

Comment: Can you verify that `pytest_fixture_setup` and `pytest_fixture_post_finalizer` actually works? I placed functions in a testdir `conftest.py` and they were not called. `pytest_runtest_setup` was called however

Comment: Note those hooks are available in pytest 3.0 onwards. Which version are you using?

Comment: Could you post the exact code you tried somewhere? I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was running `py.test test/test_something.py` with hooks in `test/conftest.py` the hooks didn't get picked up. But running with `py.test test_something.py` with the directory changed to child directory it worked. The `pytest_runtest_setup` hook got called in both cases.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a concrete example of how to do this:

```
import logging
import time

import pytest

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_fixture_setup(fixturedef, request):
    start = time.time()

    yield

    end = time.time()

    logger.info(
        'pytest_fixture_setup'
        f', request={request}'
        f', time={end - start}'
    )
```

With output similar to:

```
2018-10-29 20:43:18,783 - INFO pytest_fixture_setup, request=<SubRequest 'some_data_source' for <Function 'test_ruleset_customer_to_campaign'>>, time=3.4723987579345703
```

The magic is [hookwrapper](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#hookwrapper-executing-around-other-hooks):

> pytest plugins can implement hook wrappers which wrap the execution of other hook implementations. A hook wrapper is a generator function which yields exactly once. When pytest invokes hooks it first executes hook wrappers and passes the same arguments as to the regular hooks.

One fairly important gotcha that I ran into is that the `conftest.py` has to be in your project's root folder in order to pick up the `pytest_fixture_setup` hook.

Comment: Thanks, that was useful. One minor change though: `f', time={end - start:.3f}'` makes the output more readable (otherwise some of the times go into scientific notation).